# Node.JS write to stdout without a newline

Tags: node.js, stdout

I have the feeling that is probably not possible:
I am trying to print on the terminal text without a new line.
I have tried `process.stdout.write` and `npm jetty` but they all seem to automatically append a new line at the end.

Is it possible to write to `stdout` without having an automatic newline?
Just to be clear: I am not concerned about browsers, I am only interested in UNIX/Linux writing what in *C/C++* would be the equivalent of:

```
std::cout << "blah";
printf("blah");
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`process.stdout.write()` does not automatically add a new line. If you post precise details about why you think it does, we can probably tell you how you are getting confused, but while `console.log()` **does** add a newline, `process.stdout.write()` has no frills and will not write anything you don't explicitly pass to it.

Here's a shell session providing supporting evidence:

```
echo 'process.stdout.write("123")' > program.js

node program.js | wc -c
       3
```

Comment: Same output as what you've posted, but actually running it produces the newline. Is this from my terminal? I doubt it because same examples written in C/C++ do not add that newline. Is it standard behaviour from node/JavaScript?

Comment: @Ælex no this is not standard behavior in node/JavaScript, it is likely something else like you are saying (terminal, environment variables, etc.)

Comment: I think you are not distinguishing the output from node itself from your terminal's behavior

Comment: you mean `node -e 'process.stdout.write("123")' | wc -c` ; )

Answer (score 7):

According to this link [process.stdout.write()](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdout):

`console.log` equivalent could look like this:

```
console.log = function(msg) {
  process.stdout.write(`${msg}\n`);
};
```

So `process.stdout.write` should meet your request...